# The return type 'Future<Image>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: json, rest, flutter, dart

I'm sending login info to an api and getting a image id number that I send back to the api to get the image and i want to display the images in a grid but i'm getting a "The return type 'Future' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context." error.

the error is on the recentAlbumArt function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_music_app/API/api_call.dart';

import 'package:test_music_app/API/auth.dart';

class RecentlyAddedAlbums extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecentlyAddedAlbumsState createState() => _RecentlyAddedAlbumsState();
}

class _RecentlyAddedAlbumsState extends State<RecentlyAddedAlbums> {
  Future<List<Album>> albums;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchRecentlyAddedAlbums(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Album>> data) {
              switch (data.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text(
                    "none",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  );
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
                  ));
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (data.hasData) {
                    List<Album> albums = data.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: albums.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return FutureBuilder(
                            future: recentAlbumArt(albums[index].coverArt),
                            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot data) {
                              switch (data.connectionState) {
                                case ConnectionState.none:
                                  return Text(
                                    "none",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  );
                                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                  return Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                        Colors.black),
                                  ));
                                case ConnectionState.active:
                                  return Text('');
                                case ConnectionState.done:
                                  if (data.hasData) {
                                    return recentAlbumArt(
                                            albums[index].coverArt)
                                        .then((coverArtList) {
                                      return Image.network(coverArtList[index]);
                                    });
                                  }
                              }
                            });
                      },
                    );
                  }
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the two functions:

```
Future<List<Album>> fetchRecentlyAddedAlbums() async {
  try {
    var salt = randomToken(6);
    var token = makeToken("$password", "$salt");
    var uRL =
        "$server/rest/getAlbumList?u=$username&t=$token&s=$salt&v=$tapeOutVerison&c=$client$format&type=newest";
    var authresponse = await http.get(uRL);
    if (authresponse.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsondata = jsonDecode(authresponse.body);
      var data = apicallFromJson(jsondata);
      var aresponse = data.subsonicResponse.albumList.album;
      return aresponse;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

//TODO: build the cover art fetching within the album list or build it outside
Future recentAlbumArt(String coverArtID) async {
  try {
    var salt = randomToken(6);
    var token = makeToken("$password", "$salt");
    var uRL =
        "$server/rest/getCoverArt/?u=$username&t=$token&s=$salt&v=$tapeOutVerison&c=$client$format&id=$coverArtID";
    var coverArtList = await http.get(uRL);
    return coverArtList;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the use of your nested `FutureBuilder`. Rather than using the snapshot in the `FutureBuilder` `builder`, you are calling the `recentAlbumArt` again and returning that.

```
if (data.hasData) {
  return recentAlbumArt(//CALLING recentAlbumArt AGAIN HERE
    albums[index].coverArt)
      .then((coverArtList) {
        return Image.network(coverArtList[index]);
      });
}
```

Instead use the snapshot that the `FutureBuilder` provides.

```
if (data.hasData) {
  return Image.network((data.data)[index]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Another question it says "Class 'Response' has no instance method '[]'." is that related to the response of http request?  I don't have a class called response.

Comment: Yes it's related to the response of the http request. You're likely trying to call something on it that doesn't exist for the object type. I recommend creating a separate question for this.